# Como calcular os 4 primeiros bytes de um Address ex: 00F28758

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bitwise

Queria poder entender como calcular os 4 Bytes de um *address* para depois usar um `ReadProcessMemory`.

Queria apenas entender como calcular isso por que sempre que tento dá errado.

Vamos dizer que tenho um *Address* `181BA700` e preciso pegar os 4 bytes para calcular com um offset. Mas não entendo como fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer é algo assim?

```cs
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int Address = 0x181BA700;
        int byte1 = Address >> 24;
        int byte2 = (Address >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int byte3 = (Address >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int byte4 = Address & 0xFF;
        Console.WriteLine("A: " + byte1.ToString("X")
            + ", B: " + byte2.ToString("X")
            + ", C: " + byte3.ToString("X")
            + ", D: " + byte4.ToString("X"));
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
A: 18, B: 1B, C: A7, D: 0
```

[Veja funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/rukUQT)

Comment: Vlw.. Era isso mesmo que faltava..